# Query with jsonb operator

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'd like to make this PostgreSQL query using Npgsql 3.1.7:

```
SELECT jdoc FROM myTable where jdoc -> 'tags' @> '[{"name": "tv"}]'
```

The code looks like this:

```
using (var dbConnection = new NpgsqlConnection("myconnection")) {
      dbConnection.Open();

      var request = dbConnection.ExecuteReader("SELECT jdoc FROM myTable where jdoc -> 'tags' @> '[{\"name\": @var1}]'"),
                new { var1 = "tv" });
}
```

The jsonb operator `@>` is seen as a parameter and I get this Exception:

```
{"22P02: invalid input syntax for type json"}
Token "@" is invalid.
```

Is there a way to use this operator with an escape mechanism or something else?

Comment: Does using `@@>` help? I think the escaping should be done by doubling

Comment: Not sure about escape the `@` in the C# but in PostgreSQL you can use the function `jsonb_contains` which is used by the `@>` operator also: `... jsonb_contains(jdoc -> 'tags', '[{"name": "tv"}]') ...`

Comment: @@ is not working also.

Comment: jsonb_contains(jdoc -> 'tags','[{"name": @var}]') is not working too, i think that the mapper is lost with all the ', { and @